# Are there any simple examples for single axis zooming in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, zooming

I'm trying to learn how to make a single-axis zoom for d3's zoom behavior. Are there any simple examples that explain how to do this? I found [Mike Bostock's example](http://bl.ocks.org/jgbos/9752277), but it seems to be a little bit too complicated for me to understand.

For references sake, here's the code that I have written so far:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()

svg.call(zoom);

zoom.y(yRange);
```

For more reference's sake, I just wanted to say that I'm trying to make the y axis zoom during the zoom event.

I would appreciate any pointers/articles that could help, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following zoom function:

```
function draw() {

    vis.select("g.x.axis").call(xAxis);
    vis.select("g.y.axis").call(yAxis);


    d3.select(".myLine")
        .attr("d", lineFunc(lineData));
}
```

and added

```
.center([xRange(0), yRange(0)])
    .on("zoom", draw);
```

to my `zoom` behavior. With this, the y axis is now both zoomable and draggable.